# Custom Division with lists - divide by zero

Tags: function-construction

I have some lists of data that I need to divide by each-other, but my problem is that for some values the denominator is zero. Now these particular values are not very important, but I still need to keep them in the lists.

To solve my problem, I tried defining my own division function:

```
division[a_,b_]:=a/b
division[a_,0]=-1
```

This works great for single numbers,

```
division[52,0]
out: -1
```

but not for lists:

```
division[{1,2,0},{0,1,2}]
out: {ComplexInfinity,2,0}
```

How do I make my predefined output work for lists as well?

Of course, another solution to my problem would be to iterate over the list with e.g. a `For` loop and an `If`, but I think there should be a neater way of doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[division, Listable]
division[{1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2}]
```

> {-1, 2, 0}

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block):

```
division[a_, b_] := Quiet @ Block[{DirectedInfinity},
    DirectedInfinity[]=-1;
    Divide[a, b]
]

division[{1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2}]
```

> {-1, 2, 0}