# Efficient sinc interpolation of a list

Tags: interpolation, fourier-analysis, time-series

I'm looking for an efficient way to construct a sinc interpolation i.e. an interpolating function of a list of numbers in the form of a Fourier series with a chosen maximum frequency.
The input list is supposed to be an equidistant sample of some real smooth function (e.g. a function with a finite-support Fourier transform) and the interpolation should be a continuous function that is a sum of harmonic functions (cosine and sine functions) such that their coefficients are equal to the Fourier coefficients of the list for all frequencies up to the chosen max frequency, (see [Wikipedia: Whittaker–Shannon interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula)). Increasing the max frequency beyond the band-limit of the original function should give a perfect reconstruction of it. I'd guess there is a predefined Mathematica function doing that but I couldn't find it.

One way would be to apply `Interpolation` on the list, then `NFourierSeries` on the resulting `InterpolationFunction` (choosing the desired max frequency), but this is obviously very inefficient. `LowpassFilter` should be doing something similar but the output is a list, not a function. One option for an efficient solution that I'm trying to implement is to compute the Fourier coefficients from the list using `Fourier`, construct a function that is a list of harmonic functions with the right frequencies (e.g. `Table[Sin[2 Pi n #/T], {n, nmax}] &` for sines) and then `Dot`-multiply the two lists. I found this excellent post that computes the correct factors: [Numerical Fourier transform of a complicated function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/numerical-fourier-transform-of-a-complicated-function/1761)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ReconstructingASampledSignalUsingInterpolation/) and [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SincInterpolationForSignalReconstruction/)?

Comment: Maybe [this, too](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162768/approximation-with-radial-basis-functions/163011#163011).

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Thanks! I had seen the second one but not the first. However, these approaches wouldn't be as efficient as I need, for example they use `Sum` which is slow for large lists.

Comment: Sinc interpolation is interpolation using the assumption that the spectrum of the function is zero above the sampling rate of the function.  So if you sinc-interpolate, then do `NFourierSeries`, you should find that all the additional terms are zero.  An efficient way of doing sinc-interpolation is to Fourier transform, zero-pad the spectrum, then inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! I should read this more carefully. It seems to go a bit deeper into the efficiency aspect. It should also be possible to make it run faster using `Compile`.

Comment: @mikado OK, I see, that should indeed be the most efficient way. I just need to construct the continuous function of the Fourier sum from the Fourier coefficient list then.

Answer (score 4):

A `Sinc` interpolation can be done along the same same idea as a Lagrange interpolation:
Assuming we have equally spaced data points, we seek a function `ipol` that is 1 at x==0 and zero at every other data argument. The sum of ipol[x-x[[i]]] dat[[i]] over i gives then an interpolation function. By this the highest frequency is given by half the sample rate.

To demonstrate a `Sinc` interpolation, we first need some arbitrary test data, assuming for simplicity, that the x values are 1,2,..:

```
n = 20;
dat = Table[Exp[-x^2] Sin[ 4 x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/n}];
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Then we define a scaled Sinc that is 1 at x==0 and zero at every other integer value:

```
ipol[x_] = Sinc[2 Pi  x/2];
Plot[ipol[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, we place such an function at every data point and multiply it with the value of the data point. Then we plot it together with the original data points :

```
fun[x_] = Table[ipol[x - y], {y, Length[dat]}].dat;
Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> Point[Transpose@{Range[n + 1], dat}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Sinc[2 Pi  x/2]` is just `Sinc[Pi x]`, no?

Comment: Thanks!  I need to apply this operation on ~10000 lists of length ~1000 each, which is why I need an efficient implementation, but this simple solution may actually be sufficient for my purposes. I would first apply a `LowpassFilter` on each list with a reasonable max frequency and then construct the function list `Table[ipol[x - y], {y, Length[dat]}]` only once and `Dot`-multiply it with each of the filtered lists.

Comment: For some reasons, I would still prefer it if the output was a Fourier series instead of a sum of sinc-functions (for example I would like to be able to construct periodic interpolations as with the option `Padding -> "Periodic"` of `Interpolation`, which would be simpler using sines and cosines). But of course your solution gives the true sinc-interpolation, the truncated Fourier series is not precisely the same and it's not a true interpolation either.

Comment: Why not just use `Fourier` and remove high frequencies? Certainly it will be fast. Would it not fit with what you are trying to obtain?

Comment: You're right, that would do the job. The only remaining step is to pass from the truncated Fourier-coefficient list to a continuous function expressing the corresponding Fourier sum, which just requires the computation of the correct prefactors and list of functions. I guess this should be the most direct way to obtain the truncated Fourier sum and apparently there is no predefined Mathematica function doing this operation.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau. Hi Daniel,  I think if you truncate the Fourier transform,  the resulting back transform goes no more through the original points. You will then have a smoothing operation and no  interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference @DanielHuber. I had missed the need for an interpolation.

Comment: @DanielHuber Actually my post wasn't so clear on this: I'm interested in both the smoothing operation and the interpolation as a special case (when the number of frequencies kept is equal to the size of the original list).

Answer (score 3):

If we want to use FFT to get an expansion in circular functions we can proceed as follows:

FFT can be look at as a base change with the new base functions: `Exp[2Pi I x f]`. This is not too simple, because the FFT returns the coefficients like: First DC component, then coefficients of functions with increasing frequencies and pos. exponents. Up to the highest frequency (there may be one or two). Then down again in frequency with negative exponents.

Again we need same test data:

```
n = 20;
dat = Table[Exp[-x^2] Sin[4 x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/(n - 1)}];
ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then we calculate the FFT and if we want to smooth, truncate it:

```
fft = Fourier[dat];
smooth = 0;
If[smooth > 0, 
  If[EvenQ[n], fft[[2 + n/2 - smooth ;; n/2 + smooth]] = 0, 
   fft[[(n + 1)/2 - smooth ;; (n + 1)/2 + smooth]] = 0]];
```

We now have the coefficients of the new base and can assemble the searched for function and plot the result:

```
(*fourier synthese*)
tab = Table[
   Exp[ -2 Pi I If[i < (n + 1)/2, (i - 1), -(n + 1 - i)] (x - 1)/
      n], {i, n}] ;
fun[x_] = (tab.fft + 
     If[EvenQ[n], 
      fft[[1 + n/2]] (E^(-I \[Pi] (-1 + x)) - E^(I \[Pi] (-1 + x)))/2,
       0])/Sqrt[n];
Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, n}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> Point[Transpose[{Range[n], dat}]]]
```

No truncation:

[image]

With truncation (smooth=4):

[image]

As you see, truncation is not without drawbacks, it increases the wiggles. This is because use a rectangular window in the frequency domain. To improve, we would use a smoother window like Hamming, von Hann, ...

The function `fun` is now in exponential form. If you want it expanded in sin and cos:

```
fun[x_] = fun[x] // ComplexExpand // Chop
```